# VB.NET Filling form with graphics conundrum

Tags: vb.net, drawing, area

Afternoon, I have a maths-formula type query in VB.NET
I have a screen, it can be resized and the only input I get from the user, is the quantity of "balls" that go inside the screen.
I know I need to square root the width and height, to get my "quantity" of balls for a best-as equal rows and columns - but Im a bit stuffed on calculating:
The size of the balls.
The distance between the balls (if need-be, the balls need to be smaller)
and as per not-my example below, I need the ball start position to be at the top left corner of the form.

So, open up a copy of VS, add a new winforms project, paste the code below into the Paint event of the form and run it.

So what I need is: A indeterminate amount of balls to generate (fed by a user) to fill up the form, as equally best on the X and Y axis to fill up the form staying the same size and if possible, a little distance between them, say, a quarter of the size of the ball itself.

Feel free to resize the screen or change the _BallsInTotal variable for it to auto-generate the amount of balls.

```
Dim _BallsInTotal As Integer

    _BallsInTotal = 100


    Dim TotalColumns As Integer
    Dim TotalRows As Integer

    TotalColumns = Math.Sqrt(_BallsInTotal)
    TotalRows = Math.Sqrt(_BallsInTotal)

    Dim BallWidth As Single = 20 
    Dim BallHeight As Single = 20

    Dim BallPositionX As Long = BallWidth * 2
    Dim BallPositionY As Long = BallHeight * 2

    Dim solidBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0))

    Dim rows As Single
    Dim columns As Single

    For columns = 1 To TotalColumns
        For rows = 1 To TotalRows
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(solidBrush, BallPositionX * columns, BallPositionY * rows, BallWidth , BallHeight )
        Next
    Next
```

Ive been scratching my head for the last two hour where Im at the point where its going to bleed! (seriously, its doing my head in).

Answer (score 0):

What I've added is an InputBox that allows the user to specify the total number of balls.  I placed the code in the OnPaint event for drawing the graphics.  I've calculated the width of the columns and rows based on the form width/height.  I'm using variables for the column/row in the For loops to track which column and row I'm drawing in, then using the column/row width/height to find my x and y (plus an additional .1 of the column/row width/height for spacing).  And finally using .8 of the column/row width/height for how much space I want the ball to take up in the column/row.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim _total As Int32 = 120

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim columns As Int32 = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(_total))
    Dim rows As Int32 = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(_total))

    Dim width As Int32 = Me.ClientSize.Width
    Dim height As Int32 = Me.ClientSize.Height

    Dim columnWidth As Int32 = width / columns
    Dim rowHeight As Int32 = height / rows

    Dim brush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0))

    Me.SuspendLayout()

    Dim painted As Int32 = 0

    For r As Int32 = 0 To rows - 1
        For c As Int32 = 0 To columns - 1
            Dim x As Int32 = (c * columnWidth) + (columnWidth * 0.1)
            Dim y As Int32 = (r * rowHeight) + (rowHeight * 0.1)
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, New Rectangle(x, y, columnWidth * 0.8, rowHeight * 0.8))
            painted += 1
            If painted = _total Then
                Me.ResumeLayout()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input As String = InputBox("Enter a total.")
    Dim number As Int32 = 0
    If Int32.TryParse(input, number) Then
        _total = number
        Me.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Im just about to have something to eat so the wife is bellowing out to me - but i copy pasted that into the form and it works a treat. I'm going to spend some time reading into the code to see what you've done and understand it. It doesnt look a million miles away from my original, but I can see some graphical changes and the row heights - will be good to read on that - Thank you very much Capellan - superstar for sorting this out :)